# Cannot set local variable value

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, interceptor, dagger-hilt

I am having a wierd problem.

```
@Singleton
class AppInterceptor @Inject constructor() : Interceptor {
    private var accessToken: String? = null
    fun setAccessToken(accessToken: String?) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken
        Log.d("Tag", "Access Setting: ${this.accessToken}")
    }

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request: Request = chain.request()
        val requestBuilder: Request.Builder = request.newBuilder()
        accessToken?.let { requestBuilder.addHeader("authorization", "Bearer $it") }

        return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build())
    }
}
```

In the code above, after calling the `setAccessToken(accessToken: String?)` the first Log prints the right token, but the `intercept` function always gets `accessToken = null`. I have been struggling with this problem for hours. Does anyone know why I'm getting this issue?

To update the accessToken, I have injected the interceptor into a viewModel, then I called the setAccessToken function.

```
      @HiltViewModel
        class ApiViewModel @Inject constructor(
            private val apiHelper: APIHelper,
            private val oktaManager: OktaManager,
            private val interceptor: AppInterceptor
        ) : AndroidViewModel() {
        
            fun getResult() {
                viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    interceptor.setAccessToken(oktaManager.gettingOktaToken())
                    try {
                        apiHelper.getResults()                   
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Log.e("error", e.toString())
                    }
                }
            }    
        }
```

Here is the Retrofit builder

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RetrofitBuilder {


    private const val BASE_URL = "https://myUrl"

    private val interceptor = run {
        val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        httpLoggingInterceptor.apply {
            httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        }
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideOkHTTPClient(): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .apply { addInterceptor(AppInterceptor()) }
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideObjectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
        return jacksonObjectMapper().registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
            .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
            .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofitInstance(
        client: OkHttpClient,
        objectMapper: ObjectMapper
    ): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(objectMapper))
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): IApiService {
        return retrofit.create(IApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please update how you set access token?

Comment: I'd guess the interceptor instance you have in your okhttp stack is not the same you're setting the token to. How are you adding the interceptor in the first place?

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know whether its working or not. If that also not working , you might need to have two instance creation for retrofit and interceptor for apis that does not require token and that requires token  using named injection or custom qualifiers.

Comment: @laalto if its singleton how does it create two instance? Thats a doubt I have.

Comment: @laalto In the `provideOkHTTPClient` in the retrofit builder, I'm doing `.apply { addInterceptor(AppInterceptor()) }`

Comment: @GowthamKK, Can I get the Token from sharedPreferences directly into the interceptor class?

Comment: You're creating an instance by yourself and not using one created by dagger-hilt. The singleton annotation doesn't prevent you from doing that.

Comment: Yes everytime it intercept function will call. So it will get token from prefrence everytime

Comment: As @laalto said you creating an object . And you are trying to set token in another object. So you might want inject in retrofit instead of using like 
addInterceptor(AppInterceptor()) }

Comment: @laalto I thought by annotating the AppInterceptor with `@Singleton` this would create only one instance for all the app, was I getting this wrong? if so, how can I resolve that?

Comment: @HocineElhadj . I think it might me , hilt will not consider objects you creating. It will maintain only objects it have created.

Comment: @GowthamKK, So it's wrong to annotate the AppInterceptor with @Singleton?

Comment: You can make it as singleton. But in retrofit builder. You need to inject AppInterceptor as you do in viewmodel . Instead of calling AppInterceptor() as you are doing now.Without removing @Singleton

Comment: @GowthamKK, How can I inject it into retrofit builder object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247264/discussion-between-gowtham-k-k-and-hocine-elhadj).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can try is to set the data in Shared preference in AppViewModel and get that in  intercept funtion.
One thing needs to be validated is interceptor instance used by retrofit and viewmodel are same .As its singleton injection , the access token should updating the existing object. Not sure why its not working.

**Update:**
You need add **AppInterceptor injection** in **provideOkHttpClient()** and use that object to **addInterceptor()**

```
   @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideOkHTTPClient(appInterceptor:AppInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .apply { addInterceptor(appInterceptor) }
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build()
    }
```